# Mysql best solution - two queries vs one query with additional column

Tags: database, performance

Which solution will be better:

1) Making two queries to database where first query is getting the user id, and the second query is using this user id to query another table.

2) Adding user id column to second table and making only one query (to this second tab). Is this way a good practical to store a user id in every row this table contains?

User id column contains an integer.

First option will save more space but will be slower than the second one.
Which solution do you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The question you’re asking is really about normalisation and denormalisation, and the answer depends on how you intend to use the database more widely.

Essentially, a normalised database is good if your data could change often and you want to guarantee everyone will always see the most up to date data. If this is true you should keep each data item in only one place (except for foreign keys), and use joins to query the database. This is your option one, but getting MySQL to do the work of running the second query automatically for you - look up the inner join syntax.

A denormalised database is good for data which changes rarely, and allows more efficient read access, which might perhaps not be perfectly up to date, depending on your design. In this case you duplicate data wherever necessary, and make sure to update it in all the relevant places when it changes.

The second option is harder to build correctly and maintain, so unless you have a pressing reason for it you should probably just use a query with an inner join in it.